# How to get a dot or a comma at the end of a sentence in Hebrew?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typesetting, cc-2015

I'm trying to write in Hebrew, which is written from right to left. I'm using Illustrator CC 2015.

The problem is when I try to write anything that is not a letter, like a dot, comma, slash, etc…

These all come at the beginning of the sentence, instead of at the end, where I want it.

This issue only appears if I want to type something at the end of my sentence, if it's in the middle everything is fine.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Illustrator is pretty bad with right-to-left in my experience.
I would recommend going with InDesign if possible.

If not already, install the Middle Eastern version of InDesign, so you got all tools you need.

Then make sure text is set to:

- Right to left in Paragraph panel
- Correct language in Character panel
- Adobe Single-line Composer in top right menu

Also, for multiple columns:

- In Story panel set the direction to RTL.

In Illustrator, I think it is similar. I would guess it is probably the "Adobe Single-line Composer" that would fix your issue.